# Failed to upload new APK to Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, google-play

Building the release version of my application produces a manifest with a duplicate permission. The build completes successfully, but when I go to upload the new APK to production, I get the following error:

"Upload failed

Duplicate declarations of permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE with different maxSdkVersions"

In the intermediate manifests, the release AndroidManifest has the permission in question, but it only occurs once with `maxSdkVersion` (see below).

myapp/build/intermediates/manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
...
```

Note that `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is generated twice, once with the tag `uses-permission` and once with `android:uses-permission`.

This error has only occurred today; the last APK I successfully uploaded was about a week ago; no dependencies or permissions have changed in my project since that time.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do:

1. Clean project and rebuild project (I guess you did).
2. Delete manually all generated files in folder "build", and rebuild the project.
3. Check if your different gradle files have different maxSDKVersion, and make them consistent.
4. Maybe this permission is included in any third library (I know you wrote you haven't, but you should have GooglePlayServices at least, and a SDK update maybe made the conflict) and you only have to remove it.

Nevertheless, I would only specify the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission because it should also contains the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` one. If it works, maybe is not an explanation of what is happening to you but it's maybe enough.

Comment: Cleaned and closed Android studio 10 times, maxSdkVersion is not set in my gradle files, set minSdkVersion consistently in all gradle files and nothing.
The only thing that made the trick was manually deleting everything inside the Build folder and built again........problem vanished

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue as well. It turns out that one of the libraries that my project depends on includes the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but my actual project does not. Simply adding this permission to my project's manifest fixed the issue.

Comment: This worked for me as well, with the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned and closed Android studio 10 times, maxSdkVersion is not set in my gradle files, set minSdkVersion consistently in all gradle files and nothing. The only thing that made the trick was manually deleting everything inside the Build folder and built again........problem vanished